# GWT DateTimeFormat time in 12 hour format?

Tags: gwt

I'd like to print a formatted time (clientside), I'm using the following:

```
import java.util.Date;

...

Date date = new Date(); 
DateTimeFormat.getFormat(PredefinedFormat.DATE_SHORT).format(date)
```

This prints something in my browser like:

```
14:13
```

I'd like this to respect my current locale (en_US). I'm not sure why it's printing in 24-hour format, thought using the current locale would be the default behavior. Do we have to do something special to get the formatter to use the current locale? (trying this on mobile safari and latest version of firefox),

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the locale in either a meta-tag, or in a query string:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale#LocaleSpecifying

Comment: We need to explicitly choose a locale? The browser can't tell us what locale the user has set?

Comment: There is no "locale" setting in a browser. As for the device settings, many users have more than one locale enabled on their computers. Also, some users may access your app from a computer in airport/library/etc. where they may not be able to change the computer locale. Besides, if a user prefers to access your site in Spanish, do you want him to reset the locale of his computer?! The standard practice is to let users choose the language directly in your app. You can save their preferences in cookies or in their account settings.